# Equation $x^2=y^p + 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

can you help me please for solving this diophantine equation : $x^2=y^p+1$
and if you can give me a general method to studying such equation : $x^2=y^p+t$

Thanks

Comment: This is not appropriate for this forum.  For t=1, you find that x^2 is at most 10, by looking at prime factors of y.  In general, you study how squares lie between powers and find stuff studied by Pillai.  Mike Bennet (if I remember correctly) can tell you more.  Consider asking this on math.stackexchange.  Gerhard "Try Elementary Number Theoretic Methods" Paseman, 2015.11.13

Comment: Can those voting to close think about the problem for a few minutes?  If they do see a quick solution, I would certainly appreciate knowing about it.  (I can see how a proof would go, as indicated in Zudilin's answer below, but it certainly is not immediate.)

Comment: Dear OP: if you could provide more context for how this problem arose in your research, it might help alleviate the standard concern of a question not being of "research level".  (We do encourage this practice wherever possible.)

Answer (score 12):

This ($t=1$) is a particular case of the famous Catalan equation. The only solution known is $3^2=2^3+1$. The case $p=3$ was done by Euler and the case $p>3$ was done by Ko Chao in 1964 (the English proof is published in Mordell's book); E. Chein published an elementary (and very nice!) proof of Chao's theorem in 1976 (PAMS **56**, pp. 83-84).

The general $t\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ (fixed) case is a special case of Pillai's conjecture: it is expected that only finitely many solutions in integers show up.

Comment: I fixed the date of Ko Chao's publication (Sci. Sinica (Notes) 14 (1964), 457-460).

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote to the question, really: if we ignore the specifics, and "make it a better question than it is", it asks about higher-genus curves, Mordell-Weil, ABC-conjecture, and such, I think, ...

Comment: @paulgarrett Perhaps the downvote was reversed; right now none is there.

Comment: @WadimZudilin 
Chein's paper cites Nagell's previous result that $p$ divides $y+1$, I can't neither find Nagell's paper online nor prove it myself, would you please explain this?

Comment: Fedor, this divisibility result is in the heart of the resolution of Catalan's problem by Preda Mihăilescu, not just of this particular case. It is in Mordell's book but I also have all the related things recorded in Russian (http://wain.mi.ras.ru/cp/) after our 2001-02 Moscow seminar. The notes ("Elementary introduction") includes Euler's proof, Nagell's results and proofs from both Ko Chao and Chein. It is a fascinating story!

Comment: @WadimZudilin many thanks! Now I see from your notes, that Nagell's result is immediate after using Pell equation.

Answer (score 2):

For $t = 1$, your question is about a special case
of [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture), which has been proved in 2002
by Preda Mihăilescu.
In particular, for $t = 1$ the only solution is $3^2 = 2^3 + 1$.